# Apache .htaccess How to convert to nginx htaccess？

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

## apache .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]


  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

Please help me. This problem has bothered me for 3 days. Thank you very much

I try to convert it into the following

```
if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/(.*)$  /index.php/$1  last;
}
```

Authorization cannot be obtained correctly on nginx,Can cause CORS problems

I think it's because this sentence hasn't been converted successfully

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

because I don't know how to convert it

Please help me

I expect to get the converted nginx htaccess

Comment: The `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` rule is a workaround for a security feature on Apache when PHP is installed as CGI. AFAIK, this is not required on Nginx. However, `index.php?/$1` (Apache) is not the same as `/index.php/$1` in your Nginx conversion.

Comment: Thank you very much for your enthusiastic answer. I found the question myself. As you said, http_ Authorization is not necessary on nginx. My solution is as follows

Answer (score 1):

The `.htaccess` you're seeking to convert is quite standard "front controller" pattern. What it does is, for any URI, it will attempt to:

- serve the file matching the exact URI
- if the file wasn't found in the previous step, then check a directory, and attempt to serve from there (subject to `index` directives or further rewrites)
- if the directory wasn't found, route the request to `index.php`

The de-facto standard NGINX snippet that does the same, utilizes [`try_files` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files).

You'll find this used for virtually all PHP-based CMS configs for NGINX:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

The `try_files` directive, similar to `if` when being checked for file existence, [has its performance pitfalls](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-try_files-is-evil-too), so in fact, you may want to do as the article says is route unconditionally all request via PHP-FPM by default, then *some* (e.g. static assets) served by NGINX directly. Example bare-bones config for WordPress which illustrates the idea:

```
index index.html index.php;
location / {
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    # override SCRIPT_NAME which was set in fastcgi_params
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /index.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/example.com.sock;
}
location /wp-content/ { }
```

In this case `/wp-content/` is allocated as an empty location in order to ensure NGINX does not pass requests to files in it via PHP-FPM. It will serve everything directly for static files.

Thus the URL rewriting is actually eliminated, and all the performance penalty that comes with it is negated.

Answer (score -1):

This is the answer

```
if (!-f $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?s=/$1 last;
    break;
}

if (!-d $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?s=/$1 last;
    break;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Having these two expressions together does not really make sense... since one or other of the `if` expressions will _always_ be true. The net result is that the request will _always_ be rewritten to `/index.php`. (?)